# Facebook Graph API Explorer won't show all statuses

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph

I am https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?limit=250000, but it shows only statuses since 2011-09-19. 
I also tried to use https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?since=1199167200, but result was the same.

Is there any option, how to get all my statuses? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, limit greater than 100 will always return 100 result, So just request `limit=100` with `offset`

Example
for 1st 100 status
https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?limit=100&offset=0
for second 100 status
https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?limit=100&offset=100

and so on until you get empty response.